# rds(mysql) access using iam auth token - "certificate signed by unknown authority"

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, go

Trying to connect to rds (mysql) using an IAM-based token. The role has an rds-db:connect policy (among others).

A snip showing how Im attempting to connect to rds:

```
cfg, err := config.LoadDefaultConfig(ctx, config.WithRegion("us-west-2"))
if err != nil {
    log.Error("Unable to load credentials: %s", err)
}

db_host := "test1-instance-1.cstuff.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com:3306"

authToken, err := auth.BuildAuthToken(
    context.TODO(),
    db_host, // Database Endpoint (With Port)
    "us-west-2", // AWS Region
    "iamuser",   // Database Account
    cfg.Credentials,
)
if err != nil {
    panic("failed to create authentication token: " + err.Error())
}

fmt.Println(authToken)

// Create the MySQL DNS string for the DB connection
// user:password@protocol(endpoint)/dbname?<params>
connectStr := fmt.Sprintf("%s:%s@tcp(%s)/%s?allowCleartextPasswords=true&tls=true",
    "iamuser", authToken, db_host, "db_name",
)

// Use db to perform SQL operations on database
dbdbdb, err := sql.Open("mysql", connectStr)

if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

err = dbdbdb.Ping()
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

This gives me a panic at the '.Ping()' with the message : `panic: tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority`

Not sure why Im seeing this error.

---

As an aside - I normally run this app in EKS. The token it outputs there is several hundred characters long. When I run the same app in EC2 it's maybe 100 chars. Why?

If I take the token it prints in EKS and use it to connect from an EC2 it works.

Same token generated in EC2 doesn't work.

Error msg is the same either way.

Comment: EC2 isnt able to generate a valid token. Does the EC2 instance, where the script generated the short 100 char token have the role attached that worked in EKS?.

Answer (score 0):

Found a path to the answer [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/issues/1248):

You'll need to add the TLS bits like this:

```
func RegisterRDSMysqlCerts(c *http.Client) error {
    resp, err := c.Get("https://s3.amazonaws.com/rds-downloads/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem")
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    pem, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    rootCertPool := x509.NewCertPool()
    if ok := rootCertPool.AppendCertsFromPEM(pem); !ok {
        return err 
    }

    err = mysql.RegisterTLSConfig("rds", &tls.Config{RootCAs: rootCertPool, InsecureSkipVerify: true})
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
```

Add this call *before* the sql.Open.

```
err = RegisterRDSMysqlCerts(http.DefaultClient)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

Change the 'tls=true' in the DSN to be 'tls=rds'.